# Finding the inverse numerical reference in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a matrix b such as:

```
b =

    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1
```

and a vector a to be used as a pointer to b

```
a =

     1     2     3
```

using a in b b(a,:) we have

```
16     2     3    13
 5    11    10     8
 9     7     6    12
```

I would like to know the FASTEST WAY to find the inverse reference, which is the a reference that would give me the output:

```
 4    14    15     1
```

Unfortunately, these references cannot be stored as logical since I'm pointing to very big data matrices.

Comment: One solution : `b(~ismember(1:size(b,2),a),:)`

Comment: You might be able to improve performance on @obchardon's suggestion by using [`ismembc`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/ismembc-undocumented-helper-function) but these solutions (and most others I can think of) will give you full logical vectors. I'm a bit worried, though, when someone asks for the FASTEST way to access matrices and then selects entire rows rather than organizing their data so that they are selecting columns.

Comment: I'm sticking with the ismember solution.

Comment: What do you mean the references can't be stored as logical?  The `ismember` solution is still creating a full logical array the size of all of the possible row indices, it's just scoping it to temporary. The answer here really depends on what you plan to do with the "inverse" indices.  If you're planning on making a copy of the matrix by extracting the rows that aren't in a, then just do `c = b; c(a,:) = [];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A logical value only uses one byte and a numeric index uses 8 byte.

So indices and inverse of them totally use 8 * size(b,1)

But logical index and its inverse only use 2 * size(b,1)

Then it is efficient to use `logical index` !